# Как создать такой AlertDialog (скриншот прилагается)

Tags: java, android

Как сделать такой вот `AlertDialog`, в котором можно будет выбрать изображения, и, также, поддержка такого окна на андроиде поздних версий, такие как `android 2.3.7 (2.3.4)`
Вот скриншот:
[image: AlertDialog]

Может кто-то узнал, но это стандартный выбор лаунчера в `андроиде 4.2.2`
Тут я понял надо использовать `xml`, чтобы это окошко работало на старых андроидах. Но мне хотя бы пример реализации такого окна.

Answer (score 1):

Для создания Customize AlertDialog можно использовать следующий код (проверял на api 10+)

```
View myView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_layout, null); //имя кастомной xml

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(myView);
    builder.setTitle("Диалог");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Принять", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //action to do
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Если не стоит цель сделать именно через AlertDialog, то можно через отдельное активити.
Пропишем в манефесте ее прозрачность

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

в стили добавим

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

И работаем как с обычной активити.

Comment: Хм, посмотрел код это создание обычного alert с wiev, а вот где код можно найти, а еще лучше тот xml файл который в стандарт окне, или описать создание, выбора, просто надо точь в точь без своих заморошек с этим поставлением изображений, я даже не знаю как сделать выбор их, чтоб отмечалось синим